# how to make singular matrix becomes non-singular using pseudo inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I have a problem of making a slight change on a singular matrix to make that matrix become full rank.

My thought is to add some numbers to the diagonal to recover some 0 eigenvalues, so that the transformation will not loss dimensions. However, this is more of a thought, and I want to know if there is a formula to do this.

I got a hint that there is a way to do this using pseudo inverse and svd, but I don't know how to prove that the svd result is actually invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take $A$ to be our singular (presumably square) matrix.

First of all, it should be noted that adding a random matrix $M$ will (with "very high probability") give us a non-singular $A + M$; I'm not sure how to prove this in an elementary way, but this is easy to verify experimentally.

Second, here's the idea that they probably had in mind.  Suppose that $A = U \Sigma V^T$ is a singular-value decomposition, and we have
$$
\Sigma = \pmatrix{S & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
where $S$ is a diagonal $r \times r$ matrix whose diagonal contains the non-zero singular values of $A$.  For any small number $\epsilon > 0$, we can define
$$
\Delta A = \epsilon \cdot U\pmatrix{0&0\\0&I}V^T.
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that $A + \Delta A$ has full rank.

Comment: I don't see a way to express this in terms of the pseudoinverse, so I might be missing what they're hinting at.

Comment: OK, I tried this method, but now depends on the value of e, I got not PSD error or singular matrix error. How can I further fix this?

Comment: That's very strange.  As long as $\epsilon$ is large enough (in practice $\epsilon \geq 10^{-10}$ should be fine), you shouldn't be getting a singular matrix error.  Are all your sizes correct? Are you using a size $(n-r) \times (n-r)$ identity matrix for $I$?

Comment: @TonyLucas You should consider making another post where you ask about the problem you're having and include the code that you're using